# how to write an intersection function for type-level lists

Tags: haskell

I'm working on type-level lists of operating systems, and I wrote two type-level functions, one to combine two lists, and the other to take their intersection. I'm having trouble getting the intersection function to work right.

(ghc 7.10.3)

Here's the combine function, working as expected:

```
*Main> (combineSupportedOS debian freeBSD)  :: OSList '[OSDebian, OSFreeBSD]
OSList [OSDebian,OSFreeBSD]
```

Here's the intersection function, not quite working:

```
*Main> (intersectSupportedOS debian debian)  :: OSList '[OSDebian]
Couldn't match expected type ‘IntersectOSList ['OSDebian] '['OSDebian]’
            with actual type ‘'['OSDebian]’
```

How can I convince the type checker that this is well typed?

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, PolyKinds, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Data.String
import Data.Type.Bool
import Data.Type.Equality

data SupportedOS = OSDebian | OSFreeBSD
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data OSList (os :: [SupportedOS]) = OSList [SupportedOS]
    deriving (Show, Eq)

debian :: OSList '[OSDebian]
debian = typeOS OSDebian

freeBSD :: OSList '[OSFreeBSD]
freeBSD = typeOS OSFreeBSD

typeOS :: SupportedOS -> OSList os
typeOS o = OSList [o]

combineSupportedOS
    :: (r ~ ConcatOSList l1 l2)
    => OSList l1
    -> OSList l2
    -> OSList r
combineSupportedOS (OSList l1) (OSList l2) = OSList (l1 ++ l2)

type family ConcatOSList (list1 :: [a]) (list2 :: [a]) :: [a]
type instance ConcatOSList '[] list2 = list2
type instance ConcatOSList (a ': rest) list2 = a ': ConcatOSList rest list2

intersectSupportedOS
    :: (r ~ IntersectOSList l1 l2)
    => OSList l1
    -> OSList l2
    -> OSList r
intersectSupportedOS (OSList l1) (OSList l2) = OSList (filter (`elem` l2) l1)

type family IntersectOSList (list1 :: [a]) (list2 :: [a]) :: [a]
type instance IntersectOSList '[] list2 = list2
type instance IntersectOSList (a ': rest) list2 = 
    If (ElemOSList a list2)
        (a ': IntersectOSList rest list2)
        (IntersectOSList rest list2)

type family ElemOSList a (list :: [b]) :: Bool
type instance ElemOSList a '[] = False
type instance ElemOSList a (b ': bs) = 
    If (a == b)
        True
        (ElemOSList a bs)

type family EqOS (a :: SupportedOS) (b :: SupportedOS) where
    EqOS a a = True
    EqOS a b = False
type instance a == b = EqOS a b
```

Comment: Hmm. `IntersectOSList '[] list2 = list2` looks like a dodgy base case to me. Is there more to it?

Comment: I stared at this too long seeing nothing, but just noticed that ElemOSList's type family is wrong.  The first parameter, in particular.

Comment: and yes, base case is wrong

Comment: So, the thing I wasn't getting is, this sort of type error when working with type families means that the type checker has found a problem, not that the type checker is insuffiently intelligent.

Comment: @Joey: You can answer your own questions if you found a solution (`type family ElemOSList (a :: b) (list :: [b]) :: Bool` fixed it in my case). By the way, `If cnd True els` is `cnd || els`.

Comment: There's a package for extensible effects that does a lot of stuff like this (specifically, I remember it takes type-level unions). You may want to look at it for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

The main fix is as follows:

```
- type family ElemOSList a (list :: [b]) :: Bool
+ type family ElemOSList (a :: SupportedOS) (list :: [SupportedOS]) :: Bool
```

Also as noted there was a wrong base case.

Here's the fixed up code:

```
type family IntersectOSList (list1 :: [a]) (list2 :: [a]) :: [a]
type instance IntersectOSList '[] list2 = '[]
type instance IntersectOSList (a ': rest) list2 = 
    If (ElemOSList a list2)
            (a ': IntersectOSList rest list2)
            (IntersectOSList rest list2)

type family ElemOSList (a :: SupportedOS) (list :: [SupportedOS]) :: Bool
type instance ElemOSList a '[] = False
type instance ElemOSList a (b ': bs) = a == b || ElemOSList a bs
```